# Products and sum of cubes in Fibonacci

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, co.combinatorics, elementary-proofs, combinatorial-identities

Consider the familiar sequence of [Fibonacci numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number): $F_0=0, F_1=1, F_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}$.

Although it is rather easy to furnish an algebraic verification of the below identity, I wish to see a different approach. Hence,

> **QUESTION.** Is there a combinatorial or more conceptual reason for this "pretty" identity?
>   $$F_nF_{n-1}F_{n-2}=\frac{F_n^3-F_{n-1}^3-F_{n-2}^3}3.$$

**Caveat.** *I'm open to as many alternative replies, of course.*

**Remark.** The motivation comes as follows. Define $F_n!=F_1\cdots F_n$ and $F_0!=1$. Further, $\binom{n}k_F:=\frac{F_n!}{F_k!\cdot F_{n-k}!}$. Then, I was studying these coefficients and was lead to
$$\binom{n}3_F=\frac{F_n^3-F_{n-1}^3-F_{n-2}^3}{3!}.$$

Comment: I get a different left hand side. Rewrite the n+2 term as the sum of n+1 and n terms, and then compute the difference of cubes and divide by three. Algebraically you get the product of the n term and the n+1 term and (the sum of n+1 and n terms).  This seems to have more to do with (a+b)^n - a^n - b^n than with Fibonacci.  Gerhard "Unsure Of Any Combinatorial Interpretation" Paseman, 2019.03.26.

Comment: Thanks, edited accordingly.

Comment: $(a+b)^3 - a^3 - b^3 = 3ab(a+b)$.  If $a,b$ are consecutive Fibonacci numbers then $a+b$ is the next.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

$F_n$ is the number of compositions (ordered partitions) of $n-1$ into
parts equal to 1 or 2. The number of triples $(a,b,c)$ of such
compositions is $F_n^3$. The number such that $a,b,c$ all begin with 1
is $F_{n-1}^3$. The number such that $a,b,c$ all begin with 2 is
$F_{n-2}^3$. Otherwise either one of $a,b,c$ begins with 1 and the
others begin with 2, or vice versa. There are $3F_{n-1}F_{n-2}^2$ such
triples of the first type. Similarly there are $3F_{n-1}^2F_{n-2}$
of the second type, i.e., one of
$a,b,c$ begins with 2 and the others begin with 1. Hence
  \begin{eqnarray*} F_n^3 & = & F_{n-1}^3 + F_{n-2}^3
  +3(F_{n-1}^2F_{n-2}+F_{n-1}F_{n-2}^2)\\ & = &
   F_{n-1}^3 + F_{n-2}^3 +3F_{n-1}F_{n-2}(F_{n-1}+F_{n-2})\\ & = &
    F_{n-1}^3 + F_{n-2}^3 + 3F_nF_{n-1}F_{n-2}. \end{eqnarray*}

Comment: With the greatest respect, and mostly out of curiosity, would you really prefer such a bijective proof to the algebra in e.g. Elkies's comment?

Comment: If it's simply a matter of proving the identity, then I prefer Elkies. If you want to understand it combinatorially, then a bijective proof is better.

Comment: The OP specified a desire for "combinatorial" or "conceptual" explanations.
But the distinction between combinatorics and algebra is blurry here.
You have to choose one ball from each of three urns, each containing
$a$ amaranth and $b$ blue balls.  How many choices don't have all three balls
the same color?  On the one hand, $(a+b)^3-a^3-b^3$.  On the other,
choose any cyclic permutation of (amaranth, blue, either) to get
$3ab(a+b)$.

Comment: +1 for use of "amaranth" as a color.

Comment: This generalizes to give $F_{n-1} F_{n-2} = (F_n^2 - F_{n-1}^2 - F_{n-2}^2)/2$ (by considering pairs of compositions) but one doesn't get anything similarly nice for fourth powers as far as I can tell.

Comment: @RichardStanley: I appreciate this!

Comment: One alteration can change the last algebraic steps into combinatorial steps: after subtracting triples of 1/2-compositions of $n$ that all start with the same number, each remaining triple has a unique cyclic permutation (whence the factor of 3) where the second composition starts with 1 and the third composition starts with 2; the first composition is unrestricted, and we obtain $F_nF_{n-1}F_{n-2}$ immediately.

Answer (score 16):

This is just the following identity:
$$a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca).$$ Since $$F_n+(-F_{n-1})+(-F_{n-2})=0,$$ your formula follows.

Comment: Simpler yet: since $F_n = F_{n-1} + F_{n+2}$ it's enough to use the
two-variable identity $(a+b)^3 - a^3 - b^3 = 3ab(a+b)$
which is a quick consequence of the binomial expansion of $(a+b)^3$.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies: Thanks for this approach too.